# Change the flexbox gap property using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I'm trying to change the flexbox gap property of a div when calling a JavaScript function, but I cannot seems to access it, here is the current code:

```css
.bottomCont {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  left: 25%;
  top: 80%;
  right: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5% 5%;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="botCont" class="bottomCont">
  <div class="leftControls"></div>
  <div class="eraser"> erase </div>
  <div class="rightControls"><button id="sizeGrid" class="gridSize">CHANGE GRID SIZE</button></div>
</div>
```

Here is what I've tried to add in the main.js file, none worked:

```
document.getElementById('botCont').style.gap = 40;
document.getElementById('botCont').style.flex.gap(40);
document.getElementsByClassName('bottomCont').css('gap', '40%')
```

I tried to use console.log to inspect but I do no get any returned value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the unit as well, so

```
document.getElementById('botCont').style.gap = '40px';
```

or

```
document.getElementById('botCont').style.gap = '40%';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, such a simple fix, I'm ashamed I did not realized this, I tried wit 40% but it was returning error, I did not knew I had to use the ' '. thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

in gap property the value will be length like (px) or percentage. [check mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)

in js file you will add value with length or percentage like this:

```js
let changeGap = document.querySelector("#sizeGrid"),
    botCont = document.querySelector("#botCont");

changeGap.addEventListener("click", function () {
    botCont.style.gap = "20%";
});
```

```css
        .bottomCont {
            position: absolute;
            display: flex;
            left: 25%;
            top: 80%;
            right: 25%;
            bottom: 0;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            align-items: center;
            margin: 5% 5%;
            justify-content: center;
            gap: 10%;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="botCont" class="bottomCont">
        <div class="leftControls"></div>
        <div class="eraser"> erase </div>
        <div class="rightControls">
            <button id="sizeGrid" class="gridSize">CHANGE GRID SIZE</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```